# OpenXML copy the template documents multiple times to the new document

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a template document and would like to create a new document by copy the contents of template document multiple times.

for example, a result list count is 10, i would like to copy the template contents 10 times to the new document. 
Therefore, the process like this:

```
foreach(var item in result) {
   1. Copy template Contents to new document > replace string > add page break
   2. Copy template Contents to new document > replace string > add page break
   3. Copy template Contents to new document > replace string > add page break
   ........
}
```

1. How can i copy the contents of template document?
2. How can i read the contents by each of line to replace the string?